# macOS preferences are not being saved

Tags: macos, settings

Running macOS Sierra 10.12.5 (16F73).

After migration from my old machine to the new machine, I am experiencing an issue where some apps do not retain settings.

The migration was not trivial and I actually had to re-create the user account and then move all of the user directories by hand, including the Library directory, where the settings, I believe are stored.

The UID however did not change, so it doesn't appear to be a permission issue. I've checked the permissions and even `chown`'ed the entire Library dir just in case.

Notably, the following symptoms persist:

- Opening iTunes always displays a welcome screen and EULA, every time I open it.
- VLC always displays a welcome screen and none of the settings are saved
- Photos app displays the welcome screen, but then takes me to the correct library and shows most recent photos correctly.

And many other apps that tend to write to Library dir behave in this way. They all open as if for the first time.

However, some apps do work fine. Like Firefox and Chrome. And several others.

Any ideas what needs to be done to restore order?

Thanks.

Comment: I'm guessing you set up the new machine, then migrated as a separate step, rather than doing it at initial setup? I did that once & yes, chaos ensues :/ My solution was to merge my previously set-up data into the migrated account rather than vice versa & all was OK after that. Maybe try running the perms fixes from [Onyx](http://www.titanium.free.fr/onyx.html), just in case...